# Clip bmp images from GDSII layout

Tags: python, image

I have a large GDSII (.gds) layout containing multiple layers and would like to clip small sections of two of the layers from the layout and output as an image (.bmp or .png) file using Python. As there are many small clips to be generated (thousands) so manual clipping is not an option.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to start? I've looked in gdsCAD and gdsii and GDSpy libraries but haven't found a way to save it as an image instead of a gds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To save an image of a gdsii file using python 2.7, gdsCAD is a useful tool, but it did require a slight modification to it.

Open in your gdsCAD installation, the file core.py, and edit line 107 `plt.show()` to be commented out, and replaced by matplotlib call to `plt.saveFig()` instead.

```
    #plt.show()
    plt.saveFig("myImage.png")
```

Then to automate your saving have some logic which iterates through the gdsii and calls `layout.show("myImage.png")`, which now instead pointed to saveFig.